# Issues when trying to get golang private dependencies on CircleCI

Tags: git, go, circleci, circleci-2.0

I am using CircleCI as my tool to build my images to publish on Kubernetes.

My projects are using Golang, and I am using Go Modules.

It turns out, I am having issues when, after checking out my code, the step `go get -v -t -d ./...` runs.

At some point, for some dependencies (which are internal dependencies from my company, and they are under my company's github project), I receive `unknown revision` message.

I already configured the Machine Account, as I have my own github account set.

I have tried to add the following lines

```
- run: echo -e "Host github.com\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" > ~/.ssh/config
- run: cp key ~/.ssh/id_rsa
- run: git config --global url."ssh://git@github.com".insteadOf "https://github.com" || true
- run: git config --global gc.auto 0 || true
- run: go get -v -t -d ./...
```

The command `cp key ~/.ssh/id_rsa` copies a `ssh key` which has access to github projects, and I can use it locally to do the same steps above.

Any help would be very welcome, because I have read tons of documentations / comments over the internet, but nothing seems to work.

Thanks.

Comment: I've couple of questions, do you have `GO111MODULE=on`, what about `GOPRIVATE`? Have you checking is ssh working with `ssh -T git@github.com` on some step?

Comment: `unknown revision` implies that your `go.mod` indicates a dependency on a version that doesn't exist in the remote repo. Do you have `replace` directives in your local copy that might be overriding some of the dependency resolution behavior?

Comment: @Зелёный Yep, I have `GO111MODULE` enabled, as well as `GOPRIVATE` set.

Also, SSH is working properly, have just checked with `ssh -T git@github.com`.

Comment: @Adrian yes, for some reason it is not finding the specific tag (on my case, `v0.0.3`), but it exists. I don't have any replace directive, I double-checked now.

Comment: Are you sure the tag exists in the remote, not just your local copy?

Comment: @Adrian yes, pretty pretty sure. I have generated that tag directly on github, and I also can access through github as well.

Comment: Do you have more context on the error message (the command that's being executed, for example) ? Can you add a more complete output to your question ?

Comment: Hey @LeGEC

I've figured out my CircleCI jobs wasn't having access to private repositories, even though I was using my github user as the one which was triggering builds.
I had to create a developer token and add the config to access git like

```git config --global url."https://<my-dev-token>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/<company-slug>".insteadOf "https://github.com/<company-slug>" || true```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

- Github blocks users to get `go get` private repositories, even if the user which is running is owner (on docker - because circleCI is using docker containers to run the build)
- To overcome this problem, I have generated a developer token: https://github.com/settings/tokens
- And used the token to allow access to private repositories: `git config --global url."https://<my-dev-token>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/<company-slug>".insteadOf "https://github.com/<company-slug>" || true`

I have tested other solutions, but that was the only one which worked just fine.

Comment: that used to work for our case, however it looks like it is not working if you have a tree of dependencies and private is a nested one (like level 2)

Answer (score 0):

The well known `replace` workaround may not always work. If you have a tree of dependencies and private module is a nested one, the mod checksum validation will fail. In order to workaround this issue it is required to have an entry in a `go.mod`. Additionally, the entry should survive the `go mod tidy`. Otherwise, it may be accidentally removed.

So in addition to the `replace` solution similar to below:

```
git config --global url."https://<token>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/<org-slug>".insteadOf "https://github.com/<org-slug>"
```

(where `<token>` is your GH token that can at least read)

It is required to use a [tools](https://github.com/go-modules-by-example/index/blob/master/010_tools/README.md) approach to have go.mod keeping the entry.

Example:

```
$ cat tools.go
// +build tools

package tools

import (
    _ "github.com/<org-slug>/<dependency-name>/tools" // this is your private dependency
)
```

Make sure to have the `tools` package in the dependency repo as well.